# ImportMany only Metadata from MEF

Tags: c#, mvvm, mef, caliburn.micro

I have a custom Metadata for MEF which is declared as below

```
[MetadataAttribute]
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class ,AllowMultiple = false)]
public class ModuleAttribute : ExportAttribute ,IModuleMetadata
{
    public ModuleAttribute(string contract)
        : base(typeof(IScreen))
    {
        Name = contract;
        Region = Regions.Sidebar;
        IsVisible = true;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Module { get; set; }
    public Regions Region { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public bool IsVisible { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public short Order { get; set; }
    public short Permissions { get; set; }
}
```

As of now, I import using `ImportingConstructor`

```
private readonly IEnumerable<Lazy<IScreen, IModuleMetadata>> _modules;
[ImportingConstructor]
public SidebarViewModel([ImportMany] IEnumerable<Lazy<IScreen, IModuleMetadata>> modules)
{
    _modules= modules;            
}
```

This gives me both the Object and Metadata using Lazy<>.
The problem here is, all class that I export using MEF are `NonShared`, and I want to create a new object every time. But LazyObject.Value give me the same instance everytime.

Is there a way in MEF, where I can only Import all the Metadata and then using ExportProvider, I can get the new ViewModal object.

Comment: Lazy<T> caches a single value.  Tried removing that?  Not sure if possible...

Comment: Can you give a sample of the code where you actually call `Value` to get an instance? Are you evaluating the metadata there to see which module to instantiate?

Comment: The problem was as mentioned by @Will, since we get the value from Lazy<>, it will send the same value everytime, instead of importing from MEF, so it doesn't consider the Shared attribute here.

Comment: If you can unwrap your values and pass them in via two different arguments, does that solve your issue?  If so, you can add the details in an answer below and close out this question.